# Java Spring Controller mapped properly, but server returns 302 instead of 200

Tags: java, spring, controller, mapping, http-status-code-302

I have following controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/adwords")
public class AdwordsController
{
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView showForm(@ModelAttribute(Const.ADWORDS_COMMAND) AdwordsCommand adwordsCommand, BindingResult result)
        throws HttpSessionRequiredException
    {
        this.checkSessionExpired();

        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("adwords/adwordsRequest");

        if(adwordsCommand == null)
            adwordsCommand = new AdwordsCommand();
        User user = this.getUser();
        adwordsCommand.setEmail(user.getEmail());
        mav.addObject(Const.ADWORDS_COMMAND, adwordsCommand);

        return mav;
    }
}
```

That is mapped properly:

```
13:17:49,276  INFO RequestMappingHandlerMapping:185 - Mapped "{[/adwords],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView pl.ifirma.domeny.controller.adwords.AdwordsController.showForm(java.lang.String,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult) throws org.springframework.web.HttpSessionRequiredException
```

But when I type URL in browser I get 302 code and server redirects immediately to main page of application. Can anyone help? Why server does not return 200 or at least 404?

Adam

**@Comments:**
Such code acts exactly the same.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/adwords")
public class AdwordsController
{
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView showForm(@ModelAttribute(Const.ADWORDS_COMMAND) AdwordsCommand adwordsCommand, BindingResult result)
    {

        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("adwords/adwordsRequest");

        if(adwordsCommand == null)
            adwordsCommand = new AdwordsCommand();
        User user = this.getUser();
        adwordsCommand.setEmail(user.getEmail());
        mav.addObject(Const.ADWORDS_COMMAND, adwordsCommand);

        return mav;
    }
}
```

I wonder if this weird redirection could be caused by some spring configuration, but where to check it? And it is only place in project where problem occurs.

Comment: What's in the this.checkSessionExpired() method?

Comment: It is 100% irrelevant to the question - checked.

Comment: maybe not. do you have any logging?

Comment: It is irrelevant, because when i delete it, nothing changes... Funny is that there is no logs of that behaviour (redirecting).

Comment: this checkSessionExpired method wight actually well be related to the "throws HttpSessionRequiredException", and to to the 302 error. Better double check this method !

Comment: do you have any other controllers?

Comment: @karambolis8 could you show how do you configure view mappings? Maybe the problem is in mapping "adwords/adwordsRequest" view name from ModelAndView to an actual view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. There was a hidden redirect in a view...

Comment: I m facing similar problem. Where did you find the hidden redirection?